# Stuck in writing one VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a VBA macro. Where in sheet1 has one column "Part" and sheet2 contain one column "Analyst".

Where Part column contains numbers of parts. i want to allocate all this part to my analyst but the condition is all part should be equally allocate to analyst. Suppose my Part column contain 5 different parts and 3 Analyst are present today. like below.

Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2

[image: Sheet2]

Parts and its count

[image: Parts and its count]

my expected output-1

[image: my expected output]

Expected output sorted column Parts-2
[image]

After allocation count will be some how look like below.

[image]

Expected output sorted column Parts

I tried below Macro but it allocate only one analyst to all the part numbers.

```
    Sub AssignAnalysts()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim partRange As Range, analystRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim analystIndex As Long

    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' Find the last rows with data in each sheet
    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set ranges for Part and Analyst columns
    Set partRange = ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow1)
    Set analystRange = ws2.Range("A2:A" & lastRow2)

    ' Initialize analystIndex
    analystIndex = 1

    ' Loop through each row in the Part column
    For i = 1 To partRange.Rows.Count
        ' Get the current part
        part = partRange.Cells(i, 1).Value

        ' Loop through analysts and assign them to parts
        For j = 1 To analystRange.Rows.Count
            ' Get the current analyst
            analyst = analystRange.Cells(j, 1).Value

            ' Assign analyst to the part and increment analystIndex
            ws1.Cells(i + (j - 1) * lastRow1, 3).Value = analyst
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the result and the problem with the macro? And ideal output is not quite clear for me (what is the ideal?)

Comment: It allocate only one analyst to all parts also the count is not equal. Ideal output means expected output. Which I want. I added one more output by sorting of Part column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner/second for loop means the last analyst will always be assigned to every part. This for loop is not needed. I think this can be simplified to:

```
' Loop through each row in the Part column
    j = 1                          ' point to the first analyst
    For i = 2 To lastRow1          ' scroll through ws1 (parts)
        ' Get the analyst
        analyst = analystRange.Cells(j, 1).Value  
        ' Assign the analyst to the part
        ws1.Cells(i, 2).value = analyst
        ' point to next analyst. If end of list, cycle to top.
        j = j + 1
        if j > analystRange.Rows.Count then
            j = 1
        end if
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

This you can do without VBA with some Excel commands.

1. Insert a new column for the parts list with numbering them from 1 in column A from cell A2.
2. Sort the parts table by parts (with numbers of them).
3. Copy the analyst range (in this case (A2:A4) to one column right to the first part column.
4. Drag down the analyst name range (C2:C4) till the end of the table.
5. Sort the table on the number column to get back the original list.

There can be a slight difference in the quantity of a specific part/analyst but totally this method give an equally allocated result.